Why do we hear about women having Binah in gemara, but nothing the other way around for men? Maybe it should say something about Chochma alá Zohar?
As this Chabad page neatly gathers sources for, men are associated with Chochma, women are associated with Binah.
The gemara says that Hashem endowed women with Binah. Why is there no source that says Hashem endowed man with Chochma?
When it says "ten measures of speech were given to the world, women took nine", speech being associated with Binah, there is no equivalent converse statement for Chochma and men? In fact, Chochma is explicitly mentioned in that gemara, and is associated with Eretz Yisrael.
Is that simply not true, or is there a deeper understanding as to why, fundamentally, there is no converse statement in truth?

אין חכמה לאשה אלא בפלך is possibly such a statement

In Bereshis 41:39 Yosef is called נָב֥וֹן i.e. man of Binah, an very detail oriented man. https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.41.39?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

"The gemara says that Hashem endowed women with Binah." Actually, the Gemara says that Hashem endowed women with more Binah [than men] (שנתן הקב"ה בינה יתירה באשה יותר מבאיש). Men are endowed with some Binah, too. "Why is there no source that says Hashem endowed man with Chochma?" (1) Maybe because "Thus said  Hashem:
Let not man glory in his Chochma" (Jer. 9:22)? (2) Is man's Chochma an endowment, rather than something he acquires?

"When it says 'ten measures of speech were given to the world, women took nine' ..." The two English translations for 'שיחה' (which you translate as 'speech') brought in that link are 'conversation' and 'gossip'. The Mishnah says "Engage not in too much שיחה (speech?) with women", and that "as long as a man engages in too much שיחה (speech?) with women, he causes evil to himself, he neglects the study of the Torah, and in the end he will inherit gehinnom".
